# ThreadPoolExecutor creating duplicate threads

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I need to read a large csv file (328 MB) and process it .The processing of each row includes calling a Webservice also .

I am using ThreadPoolExecutor for first time . My logic is , i will spit every 100 rows from csv and create a thread that will run and process each row and writes the result in templ file. Once all the threads are finished , i will read the temp files and create a comined output file.

My method that splits the file and creates Threads

```
private List<Thread> invokeWS(String csvFilename, String tempFolder) {

    List<Thread> processCsvThreadList = new ArrayList<Thread>();

    //Thread Pool Executer


    int corePoolSize = 3;
    int maximumPoolSize = 6;
    long keepAliveTime = 10;
     ThreadFactory threadFactory = Executors.defaultThreadFactory();


    ThreadPoolExecutor thrdPoolEx = new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize,
            maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(2));


    try {
        BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFilename));
        String line = "";
        int i = 0;
        line = bfr.readLine();
        Thread csvThread;
        List<String> rowList = new ArrayList<String>();


        do {
            line = bfr.readLine();
            if (line != null) {

                rowList.add(line);
                i++;

                if (i % 100 == 0) {

                    csvThread = new Thread(new ProcessCsvRow(rowList,
                            tempFolder));
                    csvThread.start();
                    thrdPoolEx.execute(csvThread);

                    rowList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    processCsvThreadList.add(csvThread);
                }

            } else {
                if (null != rowList && !rowList.isEmpty()) {

                    csvThread = new Thread(new ProcessCsvRow(rowList,
                            tempFolder));
                    csvThread.start();
                    thrdPoolEx.execute(csvThread);

                    processCsvThreadList.add(csvThread);
                }
                break;
            }
        } while (true);




    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) {
        fnf.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        thrdPoolEx.shutdown();
        }
    return processCsvThreadList;
}
```

My ProcessCsvRow class

```
public class ProcessCsvRow implements Runnable {

private List<String> csvRowsList;
private String tempDir;

public ProcessCsvRow(List<String> csvRowsList, String tempDir) {

    this.csvRowsList = csvRowsList;
    this.tempDir = tempDir;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    UUID idOne = UUID.randomUUID();
    FileWriter fw = null;
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
    try {
        String res = "";
        fw = new FileWriter(new File(tempDir + "\\" + idOne.toString()+FilePropConstants.FILE_NAME_EXT_TMP));

        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        SentimentAnalyzer sentimentAnalyzer = new SentimentAnalyzer();

        for (String csvRow : csvRowsList) {
            //calling webservice for each row

            res = sentimentAnalyzer.invokeSentWS(csvRow);
            bufferedWriter.write(res);


        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (bufferedWriter != null) {
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
            }
            if (fw != null) {
                fw.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

The issue is if for 5 row csv there should be one temp file created, but when i run this program i am getting two temp files generated which is wrong . I strongly belive its not a logical issue but the way I have implemented ThreadPoolExecuter.

Any help is greatly appreciated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be creating Thread and you don't need to create a Thread pool directly.

Try

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);

es.submit(runnable); // not threads
```

BTW Each thread has to create it own output file or you need to lock a shared file, or you can submit a Callable and have it return what you want to log to the submitting thread.

Comment: Thanks Peter, it worked.I have modified my code and added       finally {
   taskExecutor.shutdown();
   try {
    taskExecutor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE,
      TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
   }
  }

Comment: Unless you really need to wait for the thread pool to finish, I would just call shutdown();

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are both starting the threads yourself, and asking the executor to execute it.

Change:

```
csvThread = new Thread(new ProcessCsvRow(rowList, tempFolder));
csvThread.start();
thrdPoolEx.execute(csvThread);

rowList = new ArrayList<String>();
processCsvThreadList.add(csvThread);
```

to:

```
csvThread = new Thread(new ProcessCsvRow(rowList, tempFolder));
thrdPoolEx.execute(csvThread);

rowList = new ArrayList<String>();
processCsvThreadList.add(csvThread);
```

Comment: @PeterLawrey - I know, but he wanted to know what he was doing wrong, so I explained. In general I think he should be using a completely different approach to the producer/consumer model then batching 100 calls per thread.